# Git - list changes in sql & conf files in part of the history

Tags: git, grep

I want to list *.sql & *.conf files that were modified between a tag and HEAD. Ideally the format would be a hash of the commit + path to the file OR
diff showing the changes.

Any ideas? I've tried looking through git log, git whatchanged and gitdiffcore man pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use git diff to display changes between two commits:

```
git diff <the tag> HEAD -- *.sql *.conf
```

Comment: add a --numstat option after diff, so you get the complete path(not shortened) if you need it.